# How to create a table in R from a csv file?

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file and am unsure how to get R to interpret it as a table because all the title info is in one cell and all the data relating to the titles is in a separate cell. So all the info I need is in 2 cells but it actually needs to be split up.
[image]

The cell A3  has a value called 'Team' , this corresponds to the part in the cell A4  that says 'Visitor'. Then each part after than corresponds to the bit below it. ..sorry I don't know how to describe it, but ultimately it would look like this …

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the field separator in your data is a `;`

`read.csv` has a parameter `sep` to change the field separator and another parameter `header` to tell it there is an initial line containing the column names.  Use `read.csv` like this:

```
data = read.csv(file="/mydir/myfile.csv", sep=";", header=T)
```

To test you can print out the first 5 lines of the data table with:

```
head(data,5)
```